# Setting port number of Firebase on socketio

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, socket.io

I am creating a react chat application using express, socketio, firebase.
URL: https://react-chat-b0e8a.firebaseapp.com/
Github: https://github.com/kaibara/React-chat

After creating the component, we run `node chatServer.js` and confirmed that the message can be sent on localhost.

However, when checking with `firebase serve`, I can not send a message.
I found out that it was enough to investigate by setting `process.env.PORT || 3000` and implemented it, but it did not solve it.

How do I configure PORT to do the same behavior as the local host on the firebase server?

I set PORT with the following three files.

chatServer.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const portNumber = process.env.PORT || 3000

server.listen(portNumber, () => {
  console.log('起動しました', 'http://localhost:' + portNumber)
})

app.use('/public', express.static('./public'))
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.redirect(302, '/public')
})

const socketio = require('socket.io')
const io = socketio.listen(server)

io.on('connection',(socket) => {
  console.log('Acces to User:', socket.client.id)
  socket.on('chatMessage',(msg) => {
    console.log('message',msg)
    io.emit('chatMessage',msg)
  })
})
```

src/components/chatApp.js

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
import ChatForm from './ChatForm'

const portNumber = process.env.PORT || 3005
const socket = socketio.connect('http://localhost:' + portNumber)

class ChatApp  extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      logs: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    socket.on('chatMessage',(obj) => {
      const logs2 = this.state.logs
      obj.key = 'key_' + (this.state.logs.length + 1)
      console.log(obj)
      logs2.unshift(obj)
      this.setState({logs: logs2})
    })
  }
  render(){
    const messages = this.state.logs.map(e => (
      <div key={e.key}>
        <span>{e.name}</span>
        <span>: {e.message}</span>
        <p />
      </div>
    ))
    return(
      <div>
        <h1 id='title'>Reactチャット</h1>
        <ChatForm />
        <div id='log'>{messages}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChatApp
```

src/components/chatForm.js

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
import AuthContainer from '../container/AuthContainers'
import firebase from '../firebase/firebase'

const portNumber = process.env.PORT || 3005
const socket = socketio.connect('http://localhost:' + portNumber)

class ChatForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      message: ''
    }
  }

  nameChanged(e){
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  }
  messageChanged(e){
    this.setState({message: e.target.value})
  }
  send(){
    socket.emit('chatMessage',{
      name: this.state.name,
      message: this.state.message
    })
    this.setState({message: ''})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id='Form'>
        <div className='Name'>
          名前:
          <br />
          { this.props.uid ?
            <input value={this.props.displayName} />:
            <input value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.nameChanged(e)} />
          }
        </div>
        <AuthContainer />
        <br />
        <div className='Message'>
          メッセージ:
          <br />
          <input value={this.state.message} onChange={e => this.messageChanged(e)} />
        </div>
        <button className='send'onClick={e => this.send()}>送信</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChatForm
```

Please cooperate in answering.

Comment: The solution to this problem is to use `Firebase` drinking.
I removed the module of `socket.io`, `express` and solved it by using `Firebase` hosting.

Comment: Thats true, believe me, if you just want real time data transfer like a chat application, set a listener on that data node with **Ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { }** at both client sides... and everytime that is updated in firebase Realtime db... it will update the other client at the other end. You wont even need socketIO! FirebaseRealTime DB works like a charm!!